# Scala Compilation Error : Value += is not member of Int

Tags: scala

I am at a beginner level in Scala, I am trying the following code:

```
var i: Int = 0

for (i <- 0 to 10) {
  if (i == 2) { 
     i += 1     
  }

  println(i)
}
```

When I increment `i` the compiler says `Value += is not member of Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Yuval's answer, you're declaring `i` twice. Not only that, but the inner one is implicitly immutable, therefore making it impossible for you to mutate it (that's why you get a compilation error).

To achieve the same effect you get from mutation you can use a guard in the for comprehension, like this:

```
for (i <- 0 to 10 if i != 2) {
  println(i)
}
```

This code can be seamlessly translated (and that's what the compiler actually does) to the following

```
(0 to 10).withFilter(i => i != 2).foreach(i => println(i))
```

Comment: ,your code is giving me the output 0134..9,but I am confused with increment of i in for loop.I can't do increment of i,
var fruits = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange","grapes","Mango")
  for( i <- 0 until fruits.length)
  {
    if(fruits(i)=="Banana")
    {
      i+=1
      println(i+ " " +fruits(i))     
    }
    else if(fruits(i)=="Orange")
    {
      i+=1
      println(i+ " " +fruits(i))       
    }
  }
  here I don't want to use another variable ,I want to increment i if IF condition satisfies, and the output be like  
  2 Orange
  Please suggest on this.

Comment: You cannot increment it because `i` is immutable. Unlike loops in other languages, when you declare `i` in the expression `i <- 1 to 10` (which is called _generator_) you are "extracting items" from the expression on the right side (`1 to 10` happens to be the method call `1.to(10)`, which returns a range from 1 to 10). If you are familiar with Java, think of it in terms of a `for each` rather than a `for-each` loop. Here you can find more information on _for-comprehensions_ in Scala: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

Comment: @SahilGurav what are you wanting to achieve? Note that "tricks" used in Java or C++ of increasing loop counters to skip some elements are probably not verbatim translatable to scala. In scala you would use collection operations and combinators instead of looping and checking conditions.  For example, adding spaces to the fruit collection would be done like: `fruits.mkString(" ")`, skipping the first element: `fruits.tail`, excluding some element `fruits.filter(fr => fr != "Orange")`. When learning scala, try to enter through the functional path. It will be more rewarding. My 2cents.

Comment: It may be translatable to Scala using a good ol' `while`.`var i = 0; while (i <= 10) { if (i == 2) i += 1; println(i); i += 1; }`

Answer (score 10):

You're declaring `i` twice, one at the outer scope and one in the inner. Your for comprehension looks at the inner `i`, which is a `val`, not a `var`, thus shadowing the external declaration.

Bind to a different name:

```
var counter: Int = 0
for (i <- 0 to 10) {
  if (i == 2) {
    counter += 1
  }

  println(counter)
}
```

Note you can do this without declaring an outer variable at all, using `count`:

```
val count = (0 to 10).count(i => i == 2)
println(count)
```

### Edit:

From your comments, I understand you want to print all numbers other than `2`. For that you need to negate your condition:

```
if (i != 2) {
  counter += 1
}
```

Or if you just want to filter out 2:

```
(0 to 10).filter(_ != 2).foreach(println)
```

### Edit 2:

From you comments, it looks like a `while` loop is better for what you're trying to achieve:

```
var i = 0
while (i < fruits.length) {
  if (fruits(i) == "Banana") {
    i += 1
    println(i + " " + fruits(i))
  } else if (fruits(i) == "Orange") {
    i += 1
    println(i + " " + fruits(i))
  }
}
```

But this code will run into an infinite loop since you're only incrementing `i` if the conditions are met. Other than that, since your doing `i + 1`, you might be going out of bounds if the last element equals "Banana" or "Orange", so you might want to rethink what you're doing. You'll probably run into an

Comment: but even if I remove declaration of i from outer scope ,it gives the same,

Comment: @SahilGurav Are you sure? Try copy and pasting the example I've supplied into your IDE and run it. Perhaps you didn't change the inner scope to `counter` instead of `i`.

Comment: There is a PR to make the error more explicit. "Can't assign to i" or similar.

Comment: here I want to print 0 1 3 4 5... 10.

Comment: Quickly running the code in the Scala shell shows that both solutions are wrong. I would use a guard to achieve this (see my answer). I guess this is confirmation bias on my part, but reasoning about mutating stuff is hard. :-)

Comment: @stefanobaghino Do explain what you mean by wrong? Running this in the console yields exactly what the OP wrote. No more, no less.

Comment: Here is the output I get by copy-pasting your code on the Scala shell: https://gist.github.com/stefanobaghino/9b4f0ccf9dfda156c8b640cfe435a2e1 Judging from his comments he wants to skip the 2, not print it twice.

Comment: @stefanobaghino His comment came a couple of minutes after I've answered his original question, which was "why can't I `+=` on my variable `i`. After that, I've edited my answer that he actually wants to negate the predicate, which was his "secondary" question which he asked in the comments. Other than that, I provided him a way to do this without needing a mutable counter. This answer was originally targeted to make him understand why his unable to increment the mutable variable, and I assume that his code isn't actually checking on `i != 2`.

Answer (score 2):

The new error mentioned in the comment looks like:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

var i: Int = 0

for(i <- 0 to 10)
{
  if (i == 2)
  { 
     i += 1     
  }

  println(i)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:19: error: value += is not a member of Int
  Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.
            i += 1
              ^
```

It should say `i` instead of `receiver` for the simple case, where the LHS is not a complex expression, but you get the idea.

Also, nobody mentioned this:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object X {
var i: Int = 0

for(i <- 0 to 10)
{
  if (i == 2)
  {
    this.i += 1
  }

  println(this.i)
}}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object X

scala> X
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
res3: X.type = X$@1129829c
```

Comment: Are you telling me that even -Xlint doesn't warn about the shadowing?